# Remote software update on Linux machines

Tags: linux, software-distribution

We develop Linux-based networking application which will run on multiple servers. We need to develop some solution for remote application update.
All I can think of now is using rpm/deb packages but we prefer not to lock this to some distro-specific solution. Besides copying files via SSH by some Bash script what would you recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: You will probably get a better answer if you use a solution targeted to your specific development platform: Java/Python/Mono/Native?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming and everything to do with system administration.  Voting to move to ServerFault.

Comment: @David Thornley: Aren't these programmers who decide how to package and distribute their own software? IMHO, it has to do with programming just like version management has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distros does vary so much in setup and dependencies, I would actually recommend you create distro specific packages and integrate with its update tool - in the end it normally saves you a ton of trouble.

With the ease of  virtualization, it's rather easy to spin up a vmware/virtualbox image foor  the various distros to create/test packaging for each of them

Answer (score 2):

How about [puppet](http://reductivelabs.com/products/puppet/)?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Blueprit and Blueprint I/O. Blueprint is a tool that detects all of the packages, files modifications and source installs on a server. It packages them up in a reusable format called a blueprint that can be applied to another server. Blueprint I/O is a tools for pushing to and pulling from another server. Both are open-source. Hope this helps.

https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint (Blueprint @ Github)

https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint-io (Blueprint I/O @ Github)

Answer (score 0):

I'm eight years late, but check [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible).

> Ansible is a radically simple IT automation platform that makes your
>   applications and systems easier to deploy. Avoid writing scripts or
>   custom code to deploy and update your applications— automate in a
>   language that approaches plain English, using SSH, with no agents to
>   install on remote systems.

Also, you can check this [guide](https://blog.versioneye.com/2014/07/03/intro-to-ansible/).